# Ignorar determinados indices em uma lista Python

Tags: python-2.7, lista

Tenho a seguinte situação:

- Possuo uma lista com 64 itens e desejo que sejam exibidos os dois primeiros valores e todos os demais após 2.

Um exemplo seria:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
```

Desejo que sejam exibidos os valores: `[1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22]`

Agradeço sinceramente pela ajuda dos que puderem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[lista[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lista), 4)]
```

Primeiro, utilizei o mecanismo de [compressão de lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para gerar a nova lista. Os valores desta lista serão sempre os valores da lista original nos índices `i` até `i+2` para cada valor de `i`. Com a estrutura `for` defini que os valores de `i` serão de 0 até o comprimento da lista original, com um passo de 4. Isto é, para `i=0`, adiciono a lista os valores on índices 0 e 1. O próximo valor de `i` será 4, adicionando os valores dos índices 4 e 5, logo os índices 2 e 3 foram ignorados. O mesmo acontece para valores maiores de `i`.

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GLbV/0).

Comment: Anderson, muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente como esperado.